# Why do I need try-catch with throws in my example?

Tags: java, multithreading

Could someone please help me to understand why do I need to use (inner) try catch if the method is declared as throwing the same exception.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    producer();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t1.join();
    }
```

syntax of producer() is

`private static void producer() throws InterruptedException`

Comment: `run` doesn't throws InterruptedException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you are defining an anonymous class.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {            
            try {
                producer(); //This is called in run method!
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The declaration of the method that calls `producer()` is `public void run()` and this method does not throw the checked exception. Therefore, you have to catch it.

Comment: so it is happening due to inner class. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's logical, because you start new thread, which can live after execution leaves the creating method(if it wasn't `main` method and if you didn't use `Thread.join()`). So you should handle exception independently.